# rake task to expire customers points balance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rake

i am trying to work out how to write a rake tasks that will run daily and find where the days remaining is 0 to update the column amount to zero.

I have the following methods defined in my model, though they don't exactly appear to be working as I am getting the following error in the view

```
undefined method `-@' for Mon, 27 Jun 2016:Date

def remaining_days
    expired? ? 0 : (self.expire_at - Date.today).to_i
  end

  def expired?
    (self.expire_at - Date.today).to_i <= 0
  end
def expire_credits
    if expired?
      self.update(:expire_at => Date.today + 6.months, :amount => 0)
    end
  end
```

with the rake tasks i have never written of these and i thought i would be able to call a method of StoreCredit that would expire the points if certain conditions are met but i am not sure how this all works

```
task :expire_credits => :environment do
  puts 'Expiring unused credits...'
  StoreCredit.expire_credits
  puts "done."
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# model/store_credit.rb
# get all store_credits that are expired on given date, default to today
scope :expire_on, -> (date = Date.current) { where("expire_at <= ?", date.beginning_of_day) }

class << self
  def expire_credits!(date = Date.current)
    # find all the expired credits on particular date, and update all together 
    self.expire_on(date).update_all(amount: 0)
  end
end
```

Since it's a rake task, I think it's more efficient to update all expired ones together

```
#rake file
result = StoreCredit.expire_credits!
puts "#{result} records updated"
```

> Retrieve Record Count Update

```
class << self
  def expire_credits!(date = Date.current)
    # find all the expired credits on particular date, and update all together 
    records = self.expire_on(date)
    records.update_all(amount: 0)
    records.length
  end
end
```

Comment: would there be a way to report how many users/records where updated?

Comment: @Paul'Whippet'McGuane updated the rake part, the result from `update_all` will give you the number of records that are updated, so just assign that to a variable and use it.

Comment: that didn't seem to get me a record count :S

Comment: @Paul'Whippet'McGuane that's weird, i tried in console, seems fine for me. I added some modification, this one should work

Answer (score 0):

You call class method but define instance method. You will need to define class method:

```
def self.expire_credits
```